# Why does Xcode simulator show the same app twice?

Tags: swift, xcode

I quit Xcode and then a day later opened the same project up. Pulled some changes from a remote repository. When I ran the app on the same simulator that I used before, two app icons show up.

One app seems to have the latest changes from git while the other doesn't. How could this have happened?

I'm on version 11.5 of Xcode.

Comment: Check the changes that you pulled. Did the bundle ID of the app change?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bundle Identifier of the app must have changed when you pulled the latest commit.

[image]

Whenever you run your app, Xcode first reinstalls the app on the Simulator. If an app with the same Bundle ID already exists on the Simulator, then it is replaced, which is why you don't see a new app every time you click "Run". However, since the Bundle ID changed to something new, the old app is not replaced.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out someone on the team made a change to the bundle identifier. I checked the project.pbxproj file history and saw a change in the bundle identifier value.